# Error installing eclipse I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, eclipse, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install eclipse using the ubuntu console on Windows 10.
I am using version 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Focus)

Now I have tried the command sudo apt install eclipse
Getting the error  package 'eclipse' has no installation candidate

So I decided to go another route I downloaded eclipse-inst-jre-linux64

Then ran the command ./eclipse-inst

and getting the log error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display

               at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:133)

               at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:813)

               at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)

               at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)

               at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:805)

               ... 32 more
```

The problem is all the examples are for Ubuntu on Linux, and not Ubunto on windows via WSL.

Comment: What version of eclipse is this and does it work on Ubuntu 20.04? You may also want to look at this web site. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: @mchid I don't recommend that Eclipse Community post, since it is almost 6 years old.  Far too much has changed in WSL between then and now for it to be useful.  Note that the "Part 2" link seems to be to the wrong post, though.

Comment: @mchid Thanks for the updated link.  And yeah, that second post uses a deprecated WSL command in the very first example.

Comment: I downloaded eclipse-jee-2002-03-R-linux-gtk. I downloaded Java, it can see the java version, but there is no java directory in /usr.
I downloaded java using sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
Maybe I should have tried downloading the oracle version, but it did not work.
Going to have to rethink this

Comment: @mchid A lot has changed that makes it obsolete.  First, at that point, WSL2 didn't exist (which is the default version now).  The `export DISPLAY=:0` only works on WSL1.  As previously mentioned, it uses deprecated commands.  Also an obsolete installation location that hasn't existed in 5 years.  And modifying files in that folder (or its new location) is now known to cause filesystem corruption in WSL1.  Just oh-so-no :-)

Comment: @TonyKavanagh I'm writing up the answer - Check back in in a few minutes.  But what version of Windows and WSL are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully installed the Linux version of Eclipse under WSL2/Ubuntu with Windows 11.

First, as a troubleshooting test, you should try something more lightweight.

```
sudo apt install xterm
xterm
```

I'm guessing you are also going to get an error with that.

You don't mention your Windows version or WSL version, but it's important to note that Windows 10 WSL does not include the ability to run *any* Linux GUI apps out-of-the-box.  Please see [How to run GUI apps with Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1580610/1210833) on Super User.  The `DISPLAY` error in the first line of the output means that you are likely trying to run it without having configured the GUI on WSL.

Under Windows 11 with WSL2/WSLg, the Eclipse installation works pretty much as expected.  There were some slight issues with dialog boxes not being properly sized (and the necessary button being "outside" the window), but I was able to work around them.

Under Windows 10, you'll need to configure a third-party X Server or run XRDP as noted in the linked answer.  For WSL1 on Windows 10, an `export DISPLAY=:0` should suffice.  For WSL2, you'll likely need something like `export DISPLAY="$(hostname).local:0"` instead.